# FINDSTR and RegEx issuse

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a batch file that asks for input, stores this input in a var and then uses the var in a ping.  I need to make sure that the input matches one of several naming conventions

Naming conventions:
`PCX1` can be as high as 100
`GENPRT1` can be as high as 100
`NETPRT1` can be as high as 100
`FAXPRT1` can be as high as 100

So if i enter 12 it will not work but if I enter PCX12 it will.

Everything in the script works except the regex.  How can i get this to work?

```
if "%sta%" == "findstr %sta% ^PCX[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]$ \i" (
    echo The syntax is correct
    goto PING
) else (
    set errmsg=The syntax is wrong
    goto START
)
```

Comment: Bad Practice IMHO - DO NOT use reserved words for Pointers, Files, Headers, etc.  It makes it extremely difficult to troubleshoot/fix scripts!!!!  I would use instead of goto PING and goto START, goto PINGER and goto STARTER ..  PING and START are reserved words with BATCH scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

`^(PCX|GENPRT|NETPRT|FAXPRT)([\d]|0[\d]|00[\d]|0[\d][\d]|[\d][\d]|100)$`

Comment: shouldn't `([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)` be more specific to OP's question?

Comment: I've written the pattern to allow for any format of up to three digits (1, 01, 001), whilst still restricting the value to 1-100. Admittedly not part of the OP's request, but though it might help.

Answer (score 0):

FINDSTR's regex flavor is *extremely* limited.  It doesn't even support alternation (`|`), so even very simple problems are going to have very messy solutions.  Here's the most compact expression I can come up with:

```
FINDSTR /R /I "^PCX[1-9][0-9]?$ ^PCX100$ ^GENPRT[1-9][0-9]?$ ^GENPRT100$ ^NETPRT[1-9][0-9]?$ ^NETPRT100$ ^FAXPRT[1-9][0-9]?$ ^FAXPRT100$"
```

Each space-separated sequence is treated as a separate regex, so this tries to perform up to eight matches on each string it tests.  That's not to say it's slow, but it's a pain in the butt to use when you're used to real regexes.

For reference, here's how I would have written that in a serous regex flavor:

```
^(PCX|((GEN|NET|FAX)PRT))([1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

If you have the option of using a different tool (like PowerShell, which uses .NET's very powerful and feature-rich regex flavor), I strongly recommend you do so.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

:start
    set /p "sta=What ? "

    cmd /v /d /q /c "(echo(!sta!)" ^
     | findstr /i /r /b /e "PCX[0-9]* GENPRT[0-9]* NETPRT[0-9]* FAXPRT[0-9]*" ^
     | findstr /r /e "[^0-9][1-9] [^0-9][1-9][0-9] [^0-9]100" > nul 

    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo The syntax is wrong
        goto :start
    )

    echo The syntax is correct
```

A new `cmd` instance is used to ensure the tested string will not include any parser added space at the end. The output of the `echo` command is tested to see if it matches any of the starting strings followed by numbers up to the end. Then it is tested again for a valid number range.

If errorlevel is set, the value does not match the condition and a new value is requested.

If errorlevel is not set, the value is correct.